# What is the meaning in single model instance in RetrieveAPIView in drf

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the meaning of single model instance in [RetrieveAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) in Django REST framework.And how can we use? And will it look?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding:

**single model instance**: Example we use `RetrieveAPIView`. If we read the method that handle requests to that class, that is:

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

We can see `self.get_object()`, it will build a `Queryset` to get object instance from our model class using method `get()`, or rather using `get_object_or_404()`. As we know, `get()` will only take **1 object instance**, or it called **single model instance**.
Example `Book.objects.get(id=10)`.
For more detail, we can open [this link](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveAPIView.html). Start from `def retrieve` then read also `get_object()`.

Likewise on `DestroyAPIView` and `UpdateAPIView`.

**collection of model instances**: When build a `Queryset`, it using `all()` or `filter()`, according to what we wrote in `queryset = ....` or we override in `def get_queryset`. Example: `Book.objects.all()`. See [this link](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html) and read `def list`.

CMIW.